# Passing functions and image paths into another function in Python

Tags: python

I've build what turned out to be quite an extensive script and now I'm trying simplify it.
`myFunct()` repeats most often:

```
import time
import pyautogui

(...)

img1 = 'images/img1.png'
img2 = 'images/img2.png'

def doSmth1():
    # do stuff

def doSmth2():
    # do stuff

def myFunct():
        while 1:
            if pyautogui.locateOnScreen(img, confidence = 0.9) != None:
                doSmth()
                break
            else:
                time.sleep(0.5)
```

How can I pass `img1` or `img2` as `img` and `doSmth1()` or `doSmth2()` as `doSmth()` into the `myFunct()`?

Comment: Does is work to just do `def myFunct(img, doSmth)`, and then later call `myFunct(img1, doSmth1)`?

Comment: Can't believe it was that simple... Thanks!